# yii2 dynamic-form do not create kartik Select2 events

Tags: dynamic, yii2

I created a dynamic form using Yii2 dynamic-form that contains kartik Select2  widget which has select2:select in pluginEvents property.

The dynamic form create normally the fields with their attributes. However, the jquery event are not created.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by registering select2 event using kvListenEvent().

I placed the registration on afterInsert() yii2-dynamic-form event.

Comment: you would help a lot of us from pains had you added sample code. Your answer have assumption that everyone understand what those terms are

Comment: kvListenEvent("select2:select", 
// do something
});